# Comparison of two strings giving false

Tags: java

`String upcs = abc,xyz,def;`
`String ItemID = [abc, xyz, def]`

i am doing below operation

`itemID.contains(upcs);` but this is giving `false`.

Can any one tell me how to compare these two strings?

Comment: Post a [mcve] of the actual problem

Answer (score 1):

When you call `itemID.contains(upcs)` it looks for the String upcs (`"abc,xyz,def"`) in an array of Strings.

Think of it this way.

```
String upcs = "abc,xyz,def"; 
String[] ItemID = [abc, xyz, def];
ItemID.contains(upcs);
```

```
if(upcs.equals(ItemID[0]))
"abc,xyz,def".equals("abc"); // False

if(upcs.equals(ItemID[1]))
"abc,xyz,def".equals("xyz"); // False

if(upcs.equals(ItemID[2]))
"abc,xyz,def".equals("def"); // False
```

You are comparing 1 big String to other smaller individual parts of the string. If you want to get a certain part of a String, then you can use `String.subString(int, int)`

Comment: i have tried in below way

String[ ] upcsArray = upcs.split(",");
for(Sting s:upcsArray){
Assert.assertTrue(ItemID.contains(s));// true
}

Comment: Did it work? If not, please edit your question to include this. If it did, please click the grey checkmark under the votes of my question.